# How to identify all insert calls into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that requires some schema changes which definitely will leave some impact behind especially during Insert. How can I find what are the clients/stored procedure/queries that doing insert into the table and also the related query?

Is this possible to be achieved using SQL Profiler trace?

Comment: You could add an "after insert" trigger that logs information to a table. Maybe `select * from sys.sysprocesses where spid=@@spid`

Comment: You can find it through dependencies but still you have to manually search the queries used in application code

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the dependent Stored Procedures, Views, Triggers, Functions name on your table.

You need to re-verify once you get the result, whether it is a insert statement or not.

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYS.objects 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%INSERT%' 
AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%YOUR_TABLE_NME%'
```

You can change terms in `LIKE` Operator as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to find which object is referenced this table?

For sql you can use

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE CHARINDEX('mytablename', definition)>0
```

Or you can download [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)